# Crosstab Dataframe with resampled datetime from table file

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, heatmap, crosstab

Given a file like this:

```
date    uselessinfo category    uselessinfo2
2011-07-22 02:56:36 banana  1   apple
2011-02-27 17:15:44 banana  4   apple
2010-12-12 00:13:42 banana  1   apple
2010-10-12 00:13:00 banana  2   apple
```

I am using pandas to build a DataFrame:

```
data = pd.read_table(pathToFile, "\t")
```

From this I try to use simple pandas methods to build a crosstab matrix like:

```
        1   2   3   4

2010    1   1   0   0
2011    1   0   0   1
```

Where columns are categories, rows are dates bins and values are the occurrence of categories in these bins

My problem is that I don't know how to bin the datetimes either by years or month and then build the crosstab matrix.
I have seen on stackoverflow that the re-sampling function is the best way to bin datetimes and crosstab to then build the matrix:

```
data = data.resample('M', on='date').sum()
data = pd.crosstab(data.date,data.category)
```

Is there a way to combine these two functions to get the desired matrix ? Or am I totally doing wrong ?

The goal to achieve is to use this matrix to plot a seaborn heatmap looking like:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need convert `date` to [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html):

```
data = pd.read_table(pathToFile, "\t", parse_dates=['date'])

data = pd.crosstab(data.date.dt.year ,data.category)

print (data)
category  1  2  4
date             
2010      1  1  0
2011      1  0  1
```

But if need resample first by months:

```
data = data.resample('M', on='date').sum().reset_index()
data = pd.crosstab(data.date.dt.year,data.category)
```

Difference best seen if chagned data:

```
print (data)
                 date uselessinfo  category uselessinfo2
0 2011-07-22 02:56:36      banana         1        apple
1 2011-07-27 02:56:36      banana         7        apple
2 2011-08-27 17:15:44      banana         4        apple
3 2011-09-12 00:13:42      banana         1        apple
4 2011-09-12 00:13:00      banana         2        apple


data = data.resample('M', on='date').sum().reset_index()
data = pd.crosstab(data.date.dt.year,data.category)
print (data)
category  3  4  8
date             
2011      1  1  1
```

---

```
data = pd.crosstab(data.date.dt.year,data.category)
print (data)
category  1  2  4  7
date                
2011      2  1  1  1
```

Comment: Worked really fine and easy to tune !
I am just wondering about the resampling line (which I commented for now). Why the categories are changing whereas we specify that we want to resample on 'dates' ?

Comment: Hmmm, if resample by months and need dates then all dates are converted to last date of month. It is by design in pandas. Maybe alo can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling)

Comment: And ategories are changed, because it groupby by months and aggregate by sum - so categories are numbers and are summed.